# How long can i use WSAPI 1.42

Tags: java, rally, toolkit, wsapi

I read a warning message on wsapi 1.42 reference page that it is deprecated and that it will get removed soon.
What is a schedule for that?
I have a few applications using that version of wsapi. I would appreciate a time period so that I can update those apps, in time :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this WS API [deprecation schedule](https://help.rallydev.com/web-services-api-deprecation-policy), the last supported date for 1.43 was June 20, 2014.
But it does not mean that the endpoints are expected to stop working.
As far as I know currently there are no plans to remove the endpoints. If you rely on 1.43 or older endpoints, those will continue to be available in near future. 
Having said that, there is no guarantee that some of the older endpoints will not be removed or throttled. In any case there is no set date or a time frame yet.