# Rally filter dropdown for custom field for matrix

Tags: matrix, filter, rally, custom-fields

I have the following code which works.  It summarizes the defects by State and Severity. I have a dropdown to filter by Release.  This all works, but I need to have a dropdown for a custom field. If I update the code and replace Release with c_ReleaseFound, it does not work. I also tried updating "rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown" with "rally.sdk.ui.ObjectDropdown." How can I modify this code to use a custom filter? Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2012 Rally Software Development Corp. All rights reserved -->
<html>
<head>
  <title>DefectSummaryMatrix</title>
  <meta name="Name" content="App: DefectSummaryMatrix" />
  <meta name="Version" content="2012.11.21" />
  <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software" />

  <script type ="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.32/sdk.js"></script>
  <script type ="text/javascript">
    function DefectSummaryMatrix() {
    var defectData;
    var table;
    var total = "Total";
    var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('14433308115', 
    '14451834527', 
    'false', 
    'true');
    var header = rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader;
    header.showPageTools(true);
    header.removePageTool("print");
    header.addPageTool({
    key:"Previous Version",
    label:"Previous Version",
    onClick:  function() {
    if (parent && parent.window && parent.window.location) {
    parent.window.location = "http://agilecommons.org/posts/4d4d00c953";
    }
    else {
    window.location = "http://agilecommons.org/posts/4d4d00c953";
    }
    }
    });

    function initialize3DArray(rows, cols) {
            defectData = [cols];
            for (var c = 0; c <= cols; c++) {
                defectData[c] = [];
                for (var r = 0; r <= rows; r++) {
                    defectData[c][r] = [];
                }
            }
        }

        function addDefect(column, row, defect) {
            defectData[column][row].push(defect);
        }

        function setOwner(defect) {
            if (defect.Owner !== null) {
                if (defect.Owner.DisplayName !== "") {
                    defect.Owner = defect.Owner.DisplayName;
                } else {
                    defect.Owner = defect.Owner.LoginName;
                }
            } else {
                defect.Owner = "";
            }
        }

        function findIndex(value, listOfValues) {
            for (var i = 0; i < listOfValues.length; i++) {
                if (listOfValues[i] == value) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return 0;
            /* Returning 0 to accommodate having null values in the Severity field even though the object has "None" in WSAPI */
        }

    // return 3D array by Severity, state and list of defects
        function countBySeverityAndState(defectResults) {
            var maxRow = defectResults.defectPriorities.length;
            var maxCol = defectResults.defectStates.length;

            initialize3DArray(maxRow, maxCol);

            // cycle through defects and increment the appropriate state/Severity combo in the array
            var row, column;

            for (var i = 0; i < defectResults.defects.length; i++) {
                column = findIndex(defectResults.defects[i].State, defectResults.defectStates);
                row = findIndex(defectResults.defects[i].Severity, defectResults.defectPriorities);
                var defect = defectResults.defects[i];
                addDefect(column, row, defect);
                addDefect(column, maxRow, defect);
                addDefect(maxCol, row, defect);
                addDefect(maxCol, maxRow, defect);
                setOwner(defect);
            }
        }

        var defectQuery = function() {
            var selected = releaseDropdown.getSelectedName();
            var releaseQuery = '(Release.Name = "' + selected + '")';
            var queryObject = [];
            queryObject[0] = { key: 'defectStates', type: 'Defect', attribute: 'State' };
            queryObject[1] = { key: 'defectPriorities', type: 'Defect', attribute: 'Severity' };
            queryObject[2] = {
                key: 'defects',
                type: 'Defect',
                query: releaseQuery,
                fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,Environment,State,Severity,ScheduleState,ObjectID,Description,owner,DisplayName,LoginName'
            };
            rallyDataSource.findAll(queryObject, populateTable);
        };

        var destroyDefectList = function() {
            if (defectList) {
                defectList.destroy();
                defectList = null;
                var displayHeader = dojo.byId('displayHeader');

                if(displayHeader) {
                    displayHeader.innerHTML = '';
                }
            }
        };

        var populateTable = function (results) {
            var tableDiv = document.getElementById('defects');
            var states = [];
            states[0] = "&nbsp";
            for (var i = 0; i < results.defectStates.length; i++) {
                states[i + 1] = results.defectStates[i];
            }
            states[results.defectStates.length + 1] = total;

            var config = { 'columnKeys': states, 'sortingEnabled' : false };

            if (table) {
                table.destroy();
            }
            table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);

            var priorities = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < results.defectPriorities.length; j++) {
                priorities[j] = results.defectPriorities[j];
                table.setCell(j, 0, priorities[j]);
            }
            table.setCell(results.defectPriorities.length, 0, total);

            countBySeverityAndState(results);

            var onTableClick = function(obj, args) {
                var col = args.columnIndex - 1;
                if (col < 0) {
                    return;
                }
                var row = args.rowIndex;
                var displayHeaderDiv = dojo.byId('displayHeader');
                var columnText = args.columnHeader + " ";
                var rowText = obj.getCell(row, 0) + " ";
                var preface = "";
                var postface = "";
                if (columnText === total + " ") {
                    columnText = "";
                    preface = "All ";
                }
                if (rowText === " ") {
                    rowText = "";
                    postface = " Without a Severity";
                }
                if (rowText === total + " ") {
                    // rowText = "";
                    preface = "All ";
                }

                destroyDefectList();

                displayHeaderDiv.innerHTML = preface + columnText + rowText + "Defects " + postface;

                var displayDiv = dojo.byId('display');
                var defectConfig = {
                    'columnKeys': ['FormattedID','Name','Environment','State','Severity', 'Owner']
                };

                defectList = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(defectConfig);
                defectList.addRows(defectData[col][row]);
                for (var i = 0; i < defectData[col][row].length; i++) {
                    var target = rally.sdk.util.Ref.createRallyDetailUrl(defectData[col][row][i]._ref);
                    defectList.setCell(i, 0, "<a href=" + target + " target=_blank>" + defectData[col][row][i].FormattedID + "</a>");
                }

                defectList.display(displayDiv);
            };

            table.addEventListener("onCellClick", onTableClick);
            // make formattedID link to work products
            for (var col = 0; col < defectData.length; col++) {
                for (var row = 0; row < defectData[col].length; row++) {
                    table.setCell(row, col + 1, "<a href='#' onclick='return false;'>" + defectData[col][row].length + "</a>");
                }
            }
            table.display(tableDiv);
        };

        var releaseDiv = dojo.byId('release');
        var releaseDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown({}, rallyDataSource);
        var defectList = null;
        var releaseDropdownWrapper = function(obj, args) {
            destroyDefectList();
            defectQuery(obj, args);
        };
        releaseDropdown.display(releaseDiv, releaseDropdownWrapper);
    }

  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
        #release {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    #displayHeader {
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
      var appCustom = new DefectSummaryMatrix();
    }

    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="release"></div>
  <div id="defects"></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <div id="displayHeader"></div>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a legacy [AppSDK1](https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk) code. The latest version of AppSDK1 corresponds to  [WS API 1.32](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/?version=1.32) that is no longer supported per [this schedule](https://help.rallydev.com/web-services-api-deprecation-policy). See "How long can I use 1.43" [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069297/how-long-can-i-use-wsapi-1-42/26069372#26069372).

The `c_` prefix in  custom field's name would only be valid in the latest v2.0 of WS API.`c_ReleaseFound` will not work with this app.  Check with the previous version of API how this field is referenced in the object model.

Also, for a custom field try using [AttributeDropdown](https://help.rallydev.com/attribute-dropdown) instead of re-using a [ReleaseDropdown](https://help.rallydev.com/release-dropdown) for this purpose.